# New Project Tango development kit doesn't upgrade/install tango

Tags: google-project-tango

I've just received a brand new Project Tango Development Kit, but it seems to be out of date and doesn't want to install the Tango Explorer, nor does it get any OTA updates. 
Kernel version:
3.10.24-g37bdaea
Thu Dec 18 12:53:52 CST 2014
Build number
PBP5.15.031.6

If I go to the Tango Explorer in the Play Store it says it is incompatible with the device, so are all other Tango related apps, including the Tango Core (legacy) one. I have tried a factory reset butt hat doesn't seem to make a difference.
Settings>About tablet>System updates states that the system up to date is.

I'm living in the USA and have a USA google account.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been tablets that were not properly provisioned at the factory and would need to be exchanged. Please contact the Google team at
 tango-help@google.com
If you continue to have problems.

Answer (score 0):

some people comment that the OTA appears after 48 hours of having the device with an Internet connection.  I think it's something like your device has asked a petition to receive an update, and then the Google servers will make it available to your Device ID with some hours of delay!

Hope it helps.  By the way, you will be up-to-date when your Kernel shows 3.10.24-gd25b167 Fri Jun 24 09:16:20 BST 2016  Build number KOT49H.160624 as today is (2016-08-19).